# Encoding an url correctly while using a rewrite engine

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am using a mod_rewrite and a routing system extracted from Akelos Framework.

I have a very big problem while using some symbols in a search key parameter.

A routing map is following:

```
$map->connect(":lang/search/:string", array('controller' => 'search','action' => 'index'));
```

In controller now I get `$this->registry->map['params']['get']['string']` as a search keyword.

I can't find a way to properly encode a url. For example let's take a string `t\ /#%&=`

`urlencode()` gives `t%5C+%2F%23%25%26%3D` and page displays `The requested URL /site/en/search/t\+/#%&= was not found on this server.`

`rawurlencode()` gives `t%5C%20%2F%23%25%26%3D` and page displays the same.

You can download or view a router class source [here on this page](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-UiPvnVn9nWTg0YmQ1X1VGVnM/edit)

I really do not want to use base64 for url and such encodings by which you can't read anything.

In case if you need here is a `.htaccess` file contents as well:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Update**

[Here are actually working files for making tests.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-UiPvnVn9nWTg0YmQ1X1VGVnM/edit)

Please download these files and test on your server if you have time.

**Guide:**

`controllerclass.php` - Simple controller framework, enables searchcontroller.php to work by defining a class "Controller" in it

`routerclass.php` - A router class extracted from Akelos Framework, bug is probably there

`routes.php` - A place where you define your routs, in our case we have only `/search/:string`

`searchcontroller.php` - A basic application to test strings - /search/stringhere points to this file

`index.php` - Where all the initiation and routing happens to begin

`.htaccess` - I do not think an error is here

I think you won't need to make changes in `index.php`, `controllerclass.php`, `routes.php`, `searchcontroller.php`

A bug is probably in `routerclass.php` or maybe there is some fix needed in `.htaccess` which I don't believe.

Comment: Try adding `B` and `NE` flags, each one alone and combined.

Comment: Same, did not give a result.

Comment: I second adding just the B flag, so `[QSA,L,B]`

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not work. Did you try it? I try posting some working files for you guys to check it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is about [RFC 3986 Section 7.3 (Back-End Transcoding)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-7.3) regarding `urlencode` and `urldecode`. I've slightly modified the function at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php#97969:

```
function myUrlEncode($string) {
    $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%5C', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
    $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "\\", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
    return htmlspecialchars(str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string)));
}
```

Note the addition of  `%5C` => `\` and `htmlspecialchars()` (htmlspecialchars is about security rather than being able to use special characters. The input may be `<script>...`or `<h1>...` etc :) ).

So you will be using it like:

```
print("<b><i>URL Encode Tests</i></b><br /><br />
    <b>Works:</b> ".myUrlEncode($string[0])." <a href=\"".HTTP_ROOT."/search/".myUrlEncode($string[0])."\">/search/".myUrlEncode($string[0])."</a><br />
    <b>Does not work:</b> ".myUrlEncode($string[1])." <a href=\"".HTTP_ROOT."/search/".myUrlEncode($string[1])."\">/search/".myUrlEncode($string[1])."</a><br />
    <b>Does not work:</b> ".myUrlEncode($string[2])." <a href=\"".HTTP_ROOT."/search/".myUrlEncode($string[2])."\">/search/".myUrlEncode($string[2])."</a><br />
");
```

After doing that, the search string #3 (`\ /#%&=`) gives a PHP error like "Method **SearchController::t** is invalid in ...\index.php on line 30". I guess this is about the regexes in the router, so you may need to do a few adjustments there.

Comment: Note that everything works normally with regular `urlencode` if you use the search query as an url parameter, e.g. `/search/?q=...`

Comment: "the search string #3 (\ /#%&=) gives a PHP error" - that string isn't valid as it's enclosed in double-quotes, and so the slash-space is an unrecognised escape sequence.

Comment: @Danack, since the error is catched in the controller, and OP wants to catch those characters, I presume an adjustment in the router regexes would allow for a wider array of characters, such as these.

Answer (score 1):

The error given is:

> "The requested URL /**site**/en/search/"

You have the extra word 'site' in it which isn't mentioned in your question, which makes it hard to interpet, but the error appears to be coming from Apache *not* PHP.

The error says that the URLs aren't being matched by your htaccess rules. So you don't need to look inside any PHP code to figure out the error, the error is in Apache somewhere.

[Searching further](http://www.jampmark.com/web-scripting/5-solutions-to-url-encoded-slashes-problem-in-apache.html) - it's because the URL is not valid. %2f is allowed in a query string but not in the path. Because it's invalid the server is rejecting it before it hits the rewrite rules.

The link to www.jampmark.com gives the 5 solutions benefits and issues with each of those solutions but it would be inappropriate to copy that much material to here.

1. Turn on "AllowEncodedSlashes" directive in Apache
2. Replace %2F with %252F and %5C with %255C after url encoding
3. Double urlencode()
4. Use unencoded slashes
5. Replace slashes with underscores (_)

Also, there is an error in your test code at:

```
$string[2] = "t\ /#%&=";
```

Slash-space is not a valid escape sequence. You should either change the code to "t\\ /#%&=";  to avoid the backslash being interpreted as an escape character.

Comment: I actually gathered and put these files together for testing outside my real application. And `:lang/search/:string` is my case on real website which has nothing to do with files.

Comment: Yes, I have read about that before and it did not help. I don't want to replace slashes with underscores. I can make my application work without mod_rewrite but urls are uglier. I think there is error in routerclass.php because I can write an application using my current apache configuration that will make slashes and other characters like number sign (#) in url to work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the URLs that have slashes in them that you think are working? 

In your example it was the one's with slashes that failed to work - which is exactly as expected as Apache doesn't like the slashes.

Comment: I will explain. Look, everything works fine in files that I uploaded except routerclass.php behavior BECAUSE this file threats slashes as separators for different controllers, actions and `params`. For example search for `"1/2"` like this: `http://^^^/search/(string1/string2)`.

Comment: So can you show the URL encoded version of http://^^^/search/(string1/string2) that is working so we can figure out why Apache accepts?

Comment: It won't work using routerclass.php but I can add files that work on apache with basic .htaccess. (Not now because I am busy at the moment, sorry and thanks)

Comment: Did fixing the slash-space remove the final issues in your code?

Comment: No and I could not deal with these issues, nor I have created rewrite with slashes with only .htaccess. I started and had some problems so I gave it up.